# Lintian error: source-is-missing while building deb package for ubuntu

Tags: packaging, deb, lintian

I'm trying to build a deb package for a software. 
I'm following [this tutorial](http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/packaging-new-software.html) for the same.

When trying to build the package using `bzr builddeb -- -us -uc`, I'm getting a lot of lintian errors for missing files:

```
E: eyeris source: source-is-missing usr/local/bin/EyeRIS/lib64/libusb-1.0.so
```

The files are very much present in the folder mentioned.

I've tried adding lintian overrides but I'm still getting the errors.

Could there be something I'm doing wrong? Or an alternative way?

Answer (score 1):

Lintian issues can be explained via lintian-info:

```
$ lintian-info -t source-is-missing
E: source-is-missing
N:
N:   The source of the following file is missing. Lintian checked a few
N:   possible paths to find the source, and do not find it.
N:   
N:   Please repack your package to include the source or add it to
N:   "debian/missing-sources" directory.
N:   
N:   If this is a false-positive, please report a bug against Lintian.
N:   
N:   Severity: serious, Certainty: possible
N:   
N:   Check: cruft, Type: source
N:
```

So here it complains that it can find what looks like a compiled object, but not it's corresponding source code.

In the specific case of libusb, distributing the binary without source code would be a violation of its license LGPLv2.1.

In this case, my guess would be that you should remove this embedded libusb library from the package and instead make the application use the one that is already packaged in Ubuntu.